# How to write a tableview in a pdf with Java (with Itext)?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tableview

I will try to be as complete as possible.

I want to write a "tableview" in a pdf with Itext 5.

But i don't find: what is the line to write the tableview in the PDF.

I create the tableview with scenebuilder.

The application is to print a bill, the tableview is the list of the products.

There are my attempts :

```
@FXML
private TableView<Product>  tableProduct;


//Create table products
final ObservableList<Product> productSelected = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Product("Product name 1",23,23,1.0),  
        new Product("Product name 2",23,4,11.0),
        new Product("Product name 3",45,3,11.0)
);

@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    index.set(-1); //Ligne de code pour supprimer que quand on selcection:


    namecolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("name"));
    tvacolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("tva"));
    quantitycolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("quantity"));
    pucolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double>("pu"));
    totalcolumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double>("total"));

    tableProduct.setItems(productSelected);

    //get the index when clicking on table row(ligne)
      tableProduct.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
              index.set(productSelected.indexOf(newValue));
              //System.out.println("Ok index is:"+productSelected.indexOf(newValue));
          }
      });

}
===================================PDF=====================================
Document document = new Document();
try {
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(chemin));

    document.open();
    document.add(tableProduct); //Error
    document.add(tableProduct.getItems().toString()); //Error

catch (DocumentException de) {
      de.printStackTrace();
    Logger.getLogger(PDFgenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, de);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

   document.close();
```

I'm going to continue to search the solution. if i find, i put it.
Thank you for your helps so quick ;)

Comment: Please also add the code you used to create the `tableView`

Comment: Also: based on your question, I assume that you are using an old version of iText. The current version is iText 7 and you're using iText 5 or earlier. If this is your first iText project, use iText 7 and read [the tutorial about tables](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2).

Comment: I don't want to create a table. I want to get the table of my application and write it in the PDF.

Can you tell me what is the class of Itext who allow to write a "tableview"? extendable table? 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that i proprose ;)

```
public   PdfPTable TableauPrincipale() {

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5); 
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    //------------------------On créer l'objet cellule--------------------

    PdfPCell cell = null;
    //Description
    table. addCell (getCell("Description",PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));



    //TVA
    table. addCell (getCell("TVA",PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));

   //Quantity
   table. addCell (getCell("Quantity",PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));

    //P.U
    table. addCell (getCell("P.U",PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));

    //Total
    table. addCell (getCell("Total",PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));


    //CONTENU DU TABLEAU
    for(int i = 0; i <=NombresProduits ; i++)
    {
        table. addCell (getCell(tableProduct.getItems().get(i).getName(),PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));
        table.addCell(getCell(Integer.toString(tableProduct.getItems().get(i).getTva())+"%",PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));
        table.addCell(getCell((Integer.toString(tableProduct.getItems().get(i).getQuantity())),PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));
        table.addCell(getCell((Double.toString(tableProduct.getItems().get(i).getPu())),PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));
        table.addCell(getCell((Double.toString(tableProduct.getItems().get(i).getTotal()))+"€",PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER ));
    }

    return table;
} //Corps principale de l'appli

private PdfPCell getCell(String text, int alignment) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: In a comment to your question you declared *"I don't want to create a table"* but in your proposed solution that's exactly what you do.

Comment: It is true,

But in the first time, I wanted to get the value of the tableview. It was just my question.

after that for my application, i use the table to center the value.

Thank you for your accuracy

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfPTable  table = new  PdfTable(3); //where 3 is number of columns.

For(int j=0; j<tableContent.size(); j++) { //where tableContent  is  the  observable list.

  table.addCell(tableContent.get(j).getName1()); 
  // where Name 1-3 are the product you want to print.

  table.addCell(tableContent.get(j).getName2());
  table.addCell(tableContent.get(j).getName3());

}
doc.add(table).
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer iTextPDF [PDF with Table](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/101-very-simple-table)  example

```
 import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class SimplePDFTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {
        new SimplePDFTable().createPdf("sample.pdf");
    }
    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
        for(int aw = 0; aw < 16; aw++){
            table.addCell("hi");
        }
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that link-only answers aren't accepted on Stack Overflow. An answer should be self-contained and relevant in the context of the question.